# Setting Blur on CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dom, button

I know there is a way to change the focus event for a button through CSS like `button:focus {}` is there a way to change the onblur event (opposite of focus) through CSS?

Comment: `:focus` in CSS isn't an event, it's a state. The "blurred" state is just plain old `button`

Comment: Agreed @FabianSchultz